# Inverse functions and complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, inverse-function

Consider the function $f \colon \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ defined as the average between $z$ and $1/z$, that is $f(z)$ = $\frac12(z+1/z)$.

a) show that $f^{-1}(w)$ consists of two points for all $w \in \mathbb C$, except for two values of $w$.

My attempt:

I swapped the variables and got that:
$y^2= 2w-1$.

So $y=\sqrt{2w-1}$ or $y = - \sqrt{2w-1}$.

Thus these two $y$'s consist the two points for all $w \in \mathbb C$.

But what are the exceptions on $w$? I guess I found one that is $w \neq 1/2$, but what's the other?

And I don't know how to solve part b):

b) show that $f$ sends the unit circle onto the segment $[-1,1] \subset \mathbb R$ contained in the real axis.

Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: If you use curly brackets with square roots, rather than round brackets, then you're telling MathJax that you want everything to be inside the square root, instead of telling us readers: `\sqrt{2w-1}` becomes $\sqrt{2w-1}$. Same for exponents with more than one character in them: `f^{-1}` becomes $f^{-1}$. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more math formatting tips and tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $f(z)=w \iff z^2+2zw+1=0 \iff z^2-2zw+w^2=w^2-1 \iff (z-w)^2=w^2-1. $

If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the roots of $w^2-1$, then $f(z)=w \iff z=w+w_1$ or $z=w+w_2.$

We have $w_1=w_2 \iff w= \pm 1.$

For b): if $|z|=1$, then $z=e^{it}$ with $t \in \mathbb R.$ We get $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{it}+e^{-it})=\frac{1}{2}( \cos t +i \sin t + \cos t +-i \sin t)= \cos t.$

Comment: So my answer for part a) is wrong?

Comment: Yes, your answer is wrong

Comment: Ohh now I see! I made a calculation mistake while doing common denominator

Comment: Okay, so you showed that $f^{-1}(w)$ consists of two points $w = 1$ or $w=-1$, but what about the other part of the question: "except for two values of $w$?" what are those exceptions on $w$?

Comment: No. I showed that $f^{-1}(w)$ consists of the points $w+w_1$ and $w+w_2.$ These points are not distinct $ \iff w+w_1=w+w_2 \iff w_1=w_2 \iff w \in \{1,-1\}.$